# Installing Microsoft Office 2021 Professional Plus

Tags: microsoft-office

I just installed Windows Home 10 and I want to install Microsoft Office 2021 Professional Plus. I noticed that there exists Microsoft Office Home & Student also. Does having **Windows Home** means I have to install Microsoft Office **Home** or I still can install Microsoft Office 2021 **Professional Plus**?

Comment: You can install any edition and version of Office you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no restrictions on the versions of Windows 10 or 11. The [requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/microsoft-365/p/office-professional-2021/cfq7ttc0hhj9?activetab=pivot:requirementstab) show that Office Professional 2021 can be installed on Windows 10 or 11. As you have Windows 10 Home, it can be installed on your OS.